# HTTP(S) proxy using SSL certificate for any domain in Node.js

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, openssl, http-proxy

My objective is to create a http(s) proxy in Node.js so when the browser is pointed to it and makes a request, to respond with HTML from proxy server instead of response from website, for both http and https protocols **on any domain**.

For websites accessed through http:// protocol, this was done quite easily. I setup a express.js web server and pointed the browser to it. Now any website I was accessing with http://, response came from the express.js server. The *fun* started when trying to access websites with the https:// protocol (which makes sense, that's it's purpose).

Initially I was getting an empty response when accessing websites with https://, because of the **CONNECT** request made by the browser. I managed to sort this out by handling the CONNECT event on the http server and forwarding it to the (separated) https server.

At this point, I had to generate SSL CA and certificate in order to start the https server and I added the CA in the browser. This worked, I was able to get the response in browser from the https server, but with a warning. I was seeing **NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID** in Chrome, because the domain accessed was not defined in the certificate. Was able to get over that by clicking *Advanced -> Proceed to example.net*. Even with this, the browser shows in address bar the warning *Not secure*, but I don't really want that. I would like the website load without any warnings, as it would normally.

I tried lots of things here for a while, and found [this gist](https://gist.github.com/cecilemuller/9492b848eb8fe46d462abeb26656c4f8) that put me on the right track.

```
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer
basicConstraints=CA:FALSE
keyUsage = digitalSignature, nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment
subjectAltName = @alt_names
[alt_names]
DNS.1 = localhost
DNS.2 = fake1.local
DNS.3 = example.net
```

The gist helped me generate the certificate needed to make the warning disappear. The key was setting the domain name in the *alt_names* section. By adding *example.net* inside alt_names, I was able to access https://example.net without any warning, nice !

But that meant in order to access other domains like https://second-example.net, I would need to regenerate the SSL certificate with second-example.net added in alt_names section, restart the https proxy server and then it would work.

I can't really add (actually I don't know them) all the domains inside alt_names section.
I was looking at regex for setting the alt_names, but looks like it works only for subdomains.

All this is running on my own machine and I can install any (certificate, etc) inside the browser if needed.
I know this is possible because I've seen this somewhere else but can't say for sure how it works in the *backend*. I was thinking it might be possible to generate the certificate on the fly, but haven't found anything online about this and I don't think it's possible without any proxy down-time.

Any suggestions would be appreciated !

Comment: There are proxies that create certs for individual domains on-the-fly using a CA whose (static) cert is installed in client truststore(s); see [squid](https://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/SslBump) (a general proxy to do caching, routing, and screening, much like you seem to want) or burp charles fiddler mitmproxy zap and many similar commercial products often used on business/organization networks which are _intended_ to intercept requests for analysis or debugging but could be used otherwise; this is usually called (https, ssl, and/or tls) 'inspection'. Search for that.

Comment: I am using burp, and you are correct about it. It does make more sense now on how burp works correctly with (most) https websites once it's CA is installed in browser. Squid isn't much a solution to me because I would need it to work in nodejs so app has it's own logic implemented, in JS but I'll be looking into it as well.